# How do you justify a preference for the positive purely real integer in a GCD computation?

Tags: complex-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

Let's say you're trying to figure out $$\gcd(-2 + 4i, 6 + 10i).$$ Obviously $2$ is a divisor of greater norm than $1 + i$, and that's the answer I came up with. But $2i$ is also a divisor and it has the same norm as $2$ (so do $-2$ and $-2i$, but it seems obvious to me why neither of those should be the answer).

I ran through the Euclidean algorithm with pencil and paper and got $2i$ as the answer, but I think I made some silly mistake somewhere along the way. I'll doublecheck my calculations.

How do you resolve this dilemma? Or is there any dilemma here at all?

Comment: "Greatest" in this case doesn't mean having the greatest norm. Rather, if $a\mid b$ and $b\nmid a,$ then $b$ is "greater" than $a.$ So observe that $2\mid 2i$ and $2i\mid 2,$ so neither of those is "greater" than the other.

Comment: You have $(1+i)\mid 2$ and $2\nmid(1+i),$ so $2$ is "greater" in that sense than $1+i. \qquad$

Comment: The issue comes up in connection with the (real) integers also. In considering $\gcd(6,-10)$ or $\gcd(-6,10)$ or even $\gcd(6,10)$ there is no reason to prefer either 2 or -2 as "the" only correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: the $G$ in GCD means "greatest". There is no natural order on $\Bbb C$, so there is no greatest of two complex numbers.

Long answer: I assume that you are talking about Gaussian integers here. The gcd still exists in a way, but it is not unique any more: it is unique up to multiplication by a unit (a Gaussian integer of norm $1$). Therefore, "the" gcd of two Gaussian integers is a collection of four Gaussian integers. If one of them is a positive real number, this may be your "preferred" gcd, by choice/definition, for the only reason that it may seem natural. However, it may very well happen that none of them be a real number. In this case, your question can't even be raised.

Comment: The order that is relevant here should be the partial order by divisibility.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sure. The short answer was before I thought that perhaps the OP was talking about Gaussian integers. Now the denomination "short/long" may not be very well adapted.